# How can I retrieve SMS conversation in a clean way

Tags: java, android, sms

I Wanted to know how to get All SMS Conversations , eg.; me Said (date/time): blabla, Contact said: blabla , i want to retrieve all Conversation wich Uri i need and what is the Right way to do it?

Comment: i cant accept an answer if this answer doesn't help me to fix my Problem ...

Comment: It was just a suggestion, nothing else. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Content Resolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) ( **`"content://sms/inbox"`** ) can be used to read the SMS in inbox.

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();

do{
   String msgBody = "";
   for(int col=0; col < c.getColumnCount(); col++)
   {
       msgBody += " " + c.getColumnName(col) + ":" + c.getString(col);
   }
}while(c.moveToNext());
```

Here is a [sample](http://pastebin.com/iPt7MLyM) that might come in handy!